# How to remove extra Column in List View

Tags: vb.net, listview, visual-studio-2005, window

In Window Form ListView, I add columns dynamically, but I got an extra column. How to remove it? Which property can it be set?

Please check my attached screenshot below

[image: My Listview]

I added totally 5 columns. After "Approval Name" column, it's an extra one.

Comment: Add one less?  Using ListView.Columns.Remove() or ListView.SubItems.Remove() seems too silly.

Comment: Hans, pls check my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the default behavior of ListView control. There are many solutions to adjust/work around it. One of that that I have used is from [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/listviewautosize.aspx) (it essentially circles around setting the last column width to -2) where the last column is stretched out to fill the remaining space. The other solution is to divide up the width of the list view manually among the columns.

Comment: I also use your way, setting the last column width to -2. Now it works. Thanks Bala and Hans.